# Show thumbnail when hover over text

Tags: javascript, html, text, hover, thumbnails

How can I show a thumbnail (image) when I hover of text (which is not a hyperlink).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
    <div onmouseover="document.getElementById('myimg').style.display='block';"
          onmouseout="document.getElementById('myimg').style.display='none';">some text
    </div>
     <img id="myimg" style="display:none" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Stackoverflow_icon.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for! But one question, do you have any idea on how to align the thumbnail?

Comment: Align the thumb with what?  Vertically or horizontally?  You have post a link or any code so we don't know what the page looks like.

Comment: Sorry, I meant position the thumb based on your mouse position. Like a ordinary tooltip instead of it being always under the text.

Comment: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/dynamic.html has jquery tools to do what you need with a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery:

Html markup:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Sample text</p>
    <img class="thumbImage" style="display:none" src="sample.png" />
  </body> 
 </html>
```

Javascript snippet:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('p').mouseover(function(){
        // Put logic on show
        $('.thumbImage').fadeIn('slow');
   }).mouseout(function(){
        // Put logic on hide
        $('.thumbImage').fadeOut('slow');
   });
 });
```

In snippet i used `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, which adds nice fade effect.

JQuery doc: [here](http://jquery.com/)

Or you can use Jquery plugin which does it, there is a lot examples in net.